# Need To make list in selenium to find elements by xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PolarisTextField10"]').send_keys(img.value)
```

every order to add media change the number PolarisTextField[10]

I need to write a list like that

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="PolarisTextField["10,11,etc"]"]').send_keys(img.value)
```

sorry but i am beginner

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution where we are using `find_elements_by_xpath` to get all elements that starts with `PolarisTextField` id.

```
inputs = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'PolarisTextField')]"))
for inputIndex in range(inputs):
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'PolarisTextField')]")[inputIndex].send_keys("text goes here")
```

Comment: if we use the full index will choose the first text field like product name and i need to input media url only

Comment: or for the best ways can we allocate placeholder="https://" as important attribute to choose it
https://prnt.sc/rt9gve
because ebery text field has the same id and class name